# The network path was not found

Tags: c#

I had an error in my code given below:this shows an error that path to the file and server is not defined properly. Please help me to solve this problem else please suggest me some anomaly detection code to run it successfully

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace DDOS
{
    public partial class client : Form
    {

        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection cn;
        public static string fileName;
        public static string Servername;
        string path;
        public client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUname.Enabled = true;
            btnLogin.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MANIKANDAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=DDOS;Integrated Security=True");
            cn.Open();
            string server = "" + txtUname.Text + ".txt";
            Servername = "" + textBox1.Text + "";
            string path3 = "\\\\" + Servername + "/REPUTE/" + server + "";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path3))
            {
                lblError1.Text = "";
                lblError1.Text = "Contact Admin To use the tool";
                txtUname.Text = "";
                txtPass.Text = "";

            }
            else

            {
                        fileName = "uname.txt";
                        Servername = "" + textBox1.Text + "";
                        path = "\\\\" + Servername + "/REPUTE/" + fileName + "";
                        FileStream fileStr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStr);
                        sw.Write(txtUname.Text);
                        sw.Close();
                        fileStr.Close();
                        sendFile objsendfile = new sendFile();
                        objsendfile.Show();
            }
        }//i have error in this area
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) (about half way down that page) that could clean up some of your code. As could using `string.Format` rather than assembling each piece of a string together using `+`. Finally, the switch from \ to `/` as a separator in your paths looks a little suspect.

Comment: Which line exactly gives you this error?